# Sql Null Value On One Column Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I just waste Two to Three Hourse behind This Sql Transact and confused on Null Value Skip.

I have two table like below:

```
Table 1: AccountMast
companyID   accname         category
102     PURCHASE  ACCOUNT   Purchase Account
102     SALES ACCOUNT       Sales Account

Table2: Legder

companyID   name            
102     PURCHASE ACCOUNT        
102     SALES ACCOUNT
```

I have  join it as below:

```
select
case
when a.catagory='Purchase Account' then
l.name 
end as PurchaseAccount,
case
when a.catagory = 'Sales Account' then
l.name   
end as SalesAccount
from ledger l join accountmast a
on l.companyID=a.companyID
and l.name = a.accname
where l.companyID=102
and a.catagory='Purchase Account' or a.catagory='Sales Account'
group by l.name,a.catagory
```

The Result is:

```
PurchaseAccount     SaleAccount
PURCHASE ACCOUNT    NULL
NULL                SALES ACCOUNT
```

But I Want Result Like:

```
PurchaseAccount     SaleAccount
PURCHASE ACCOUNT    SALES ACCOUNT
```

How to Do It?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
select
    max(case when a.catagory = 'Purchase Account' then l.name end) as PurchaseAccount,
    max(case when a.catagory = 'Sales Account' then l.name end) as SalesAccount
from ledger l
join accountmast a
on l.companyID = a.companyID and l.name = a.accname
where l.companyID=102 and a.catagory IN ('Purchase Account', 'Sales Account')
```

Comment: Sorry but it make no difference it's shows the result as I don't won't. It shows the result as above I said.

Comment: You have miss One Thing and That is forget to remove group by l.name where you have already function it by max otherwise your code is too good So remove it then I will accept your answer as correct

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to add purchase amount in same condition.